# Text color change not reflecting in list view

Tags: android

I changed the text color and its not reflecting.. still showing black by default.Please help

I edited the "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" xml file. Is that enough or should i change something else to make it work?

```
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that programmatically by overriding the `getView` of `ArrayAdapter` like the following.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourList) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        return view;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change second argument of ArrayAdapter with selfmade xml textview file.

step 1.inside res in layout make textview_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="#00f">
</TextView>
```

step 2.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.textview_blue,arraylist_yours);
```

step 3.

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

sure this code is work for you, you may change color in xml as per your desire.
this answer will helpful correctly as per your requirement.